# Removing sidebar from categories page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, sidebar

I'm trying to remove the sidebar from my archive.php category page in WordPress. The problem is that the sidebar is included in the footer file, so I need to create a conditional statement to detect what pages are category pages. The if statement in the footer.php file reads:

```
<?php if(!is_page_template('page-full.php') && (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])!='wp-signup.php')) : ?>
</div><!-- end content -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried to add if(!is_category()) to the statement (shown bellow), but it seems to break the whole statement. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
<?php if(!is_category() || (!is_page_template('page-full.php') && (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])!='wp-signup.php')) : ?>
</div><!-- end content -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What do you want ? if `category` && `single` page then don't want to show `sidebar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (don't show `sidebar` on `category` and `single` page, `or/||` won't work)

```
<?php if(!is_category() && !is_single() ) : ?>
    </div><!-- end content -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will show `sidebar` if neither `category` nor `single` page.

Comment: @ The Alpha, I have the same question but my requirement is to remove the side bar from just the "Product Category" page. Which means the side bar should display on the Product Catalog page. What should be the code... <?php if(!is_category()) : ?>
    </div><!-- end content -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endif; ?> where should i put this code ??

Comment: Didn't get the question :p

Comment: My question is, Can i remove the sidebar only for particular URLs of my side.
If the url is like below - remove the side bar and make the page full wridth
http://www.example.com/product-category/sanitaryware/
http://www.example.com/product-category/Faucet/

I dont want to remove the sidebar for "Product Category" reason, i want the side bar to show up for the below URLs:
http://www.example.com/product-category/sanitaryware/closets/one-piece-closets/

Comment: You can use a different template i.e. `full-width.php` when creating/editing the page or you can use soomething like `if(is_page('Page Name')) : else : get_sidebar();
endif;`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the piece of modified code you provided was missing an end bracket, that might the reason for it to break.

Secondly, you should be using an && operator if you want to allow existing conditional criteria to display sidebar, so the below modified if statement might work

```
<?php if(!is_category() && !is_page_template('page-full.php') && (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])!='wp-signup.php')) : ?>
```

Hope it helps